# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: error is coming

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and hence don't have much idea about it. I am trying to create an app having the following contents in my view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from fusioncharts.models import City

def pie_chart(request):
    labels = []
    data = []

    queryset = City.objects.order_by('-population')[:3]
    for city in queryset:
        labels.append(city.name)
        data.append(city.population)

    return render(request, 'pie_chart.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

The content of my urls.py file inside the app is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from fusioncharts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('pie-chart/', views.pie_chart, name='pie-chart'),
]
```

and the content of my urls.py file inside the main project folder is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('fusioncharts.urls'))
]
```

In the settings.py file, I have added the following:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Piechart.urls'
```

and under the TEMPLATES, added the following:

```
'DIRS': ['Piechart/fusioncharts/templates'],
```

Now while running my app, I am getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'Piechart.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Can anyone please say what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you specify apps name too!!!

Comment: The name of the app is fusioncharts. The name of the main project is Piechart.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to import include in the project urls.py, i was about to comment this but can't in my current reputation level.

```
from django.urls import path,include
```